# Solidity: Error: Please pass numbers as strings or BN objects to avoid precision errors

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Have a simple contract in solidity:

```
contract SellStuff{

    address seller;
    string name;
    string description;
    uint256 price;

    function sellStuff(string memory _name, string memory _description, uint256 _price) public{
        seller = msg.sender;
        name = _name;
        description = _description;
        price = _price;
    }
    function getStuff() public view returns (
        address _seller, 
        string memory _name, 
        string memory _description, 
        uint256 _price){
            return(seller, name, description, price);
    }
}
```

And running a javascript test as follows:

```
var SellStuff= artifacts.require("./SellStuff.sol");

// Testing
contract('SellStuff', function(accounts){

    var sellStuffInstance;
    var seller = accounts[1];
    var stuffName = "stuff 1";
    var stuffDescription = "Description for stuff 1";
    var stuffPrice = 10;

    it("should sell stuff", function(){
        return SellStuff.deployed().then(function(instance){
            sellStuffInstance= instance;
            return sellStuffInstance.sellStuff(stuffName, stuffDescription, web3.utils.toWei(stuffPrice,'ether'), {from: seller});
        }).then(function(){
            //the state of the block should be updated from the last promise
            return sellStuffInstance.getStuff();
        }).then(function(data){
                assert.equal(data[0], seller, "seller must be " + seller);
                assert.equal(data[1], stuffName, "stuff name must be " +  stuffName);
                assert.equal(data[2], stuffDescription, "stuff description must be " + stuffDescription);
                assert.equal(data[3].toNumber(), web3.utils.toWei(stuffPrice,"ether"), "stuff price must be " + web3.utils.toWei(stuffPrice,"ether")); 
        });
    });
});
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Please pass numbers as string or BN objects to avoid precision errors.
```

This seems to look like it pertains to the return type from the web3.utils.toWei call, so I have tried to cast it to a string:web3.utils.toWei(stuffPrice.toString(),"ether"); but this gives the Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits.

Not sure if I need to simply change the var in the class from uint256 or if there is a better way to cast the toWei return variable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is here:

```
web3.utils.toWei(stuffPrice,'ether')
```

`stuffPrice` should be string.

```
 web3.utils.toWei(String(stuffPrice),'ether')
```

Answer (score 5):

The [toWei()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-utils.html#towei) method accepts `String|BN` as the first argument. You're passing it the `stuffPrice` as a `Number`.

---

A quick fix is to define the `stuffPrice` as `String`:

```
var stuffPrice = '10'; // corrected code, String
```

instead of

```
var stuffPrice = 10; // original code, Number
```

---

Another way is to pass it a `BN` object.

```
var stuffPrice = 10; // original code, Number

web3.utils.toWei(
    web3.utils.toBN(stuffPrice), // converts Number to BN, which is accepted by `toWei()`
    'ether'
);
```

Comment: Thanks Petr, unfortunately, as mentioned, when I try to convert to BN, or String, I am getting the Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the state variable as a string which will work in this case.

In React:

```
state = { playerEthervalue: ''};
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

// Send the ethers to transaction, initiate the transaction
await lottery.methods.getPlayersAddress().send({ from: accounts[0], 
           value: web3.utils.toWei(this.state.playerEthervalue, 'ether') });
```

In solidity(.sol):

```
function getPlayersAddress() public payable {    
 require(msg.value >= 0.00000001 ether);
 players.push(msg.sender); 
}
```